# What have I done wrong with programming a multiple choice game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a game and cant get the y/n function to work

I've tried the code below and it says y is not defined or it will just skip asking and print ("Lets go!")

```
import time
name = input ("Hello, what is your name?")
print ("Hello," +name)
time.sleep(1)
print ("ready to play? [y/n]")
y = print ("Let's go!")
```

Here's how it should look like:

```
Hello, what is your name? xyz
Hello, xyz
ready to play? [y/n] y
Let's go!
```

I wanted it to wait for my input of either y or n before it said ("Let's go!")

Comment: `print("ready to play? [y/n]")` isn't `input("ready to play? [y/n]")` and `y = print ("Let's go!")` makes little sense since `print` has no return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change `print ("ready to play? [y/n]")` to `input("ready to play? [y/n]")` and put it inside a variable. Next, remove `y = print ("Let's go!")`, and change it with this (if you want to):

```
ready_status = input("are you ready? [y/n]")
if ready_status == 'y':
    print("let's go!")
if ready_status == 'n':
    print("...")
    #do anything you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking for input on "ready to play" line you are just printing, so therefore it is not going to wait.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a wait command after your print prompt. Therefore it is not going to wait.

Try this method for inputting a wait time

```
answer = input("y/n?")
```